# Using context manager to store model parameters

Tags: python, pymc3, contextmanager

**I am looking for a minimum example on what the PyMC3 API actually does behind the scenes.** I am not able to rebuild it from looking at the source code.

Looking at PyMC3 I am confused by the API which I understand to use, but don't get how it actually works behind the scenes. The source code is to complicated for my python knowledge. I don't even know where to start.

Typical model code for PyMC3 looks like this.

```py
basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal("alpha", mu=0, sigma=10)
    beta = pm.Normal("beta", mu=0, sigma=10, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0] * X1 + beta[1] * X2

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=Y)
```

**In the documentation it states:**

> This creates a context manager, with our basic_model as the context, that includes all statements until the indented block ends. This means all PyMC3 objects introduced in the indented code block below the with statement are added to the model behind the scenes.

How does this work? I guess this must happen in the `__enter__` method of the context manager (here: the model).

Could someone give me a minimum example of a context manager "storing" what is happening within the with statement.

Comment: Just looked at the PyMC3 code, and it's a complex design, but pretty cool. If I understand correctly, it's using contexts to handle things you might thing of as "global" variables. When run inside a context, the `pm.*` functions will find the current context and store information there for use by other `pm.*` functions. This is a nice design in that you don't have to keep passing the current model to every function you call, it's implied by the context you're in instead. And it's much better than using global variables, obviously.

Comment: As to your explicit question, I think this is very advanced use of context managers, and I think a "minimum" example of this approach would be quite complex already. If you look at [`model.py`](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/main/pymc/model.py) from PyMC (I didn't find the PyMC3 source code, but this is obviously the same technique), it's all implemented in the `ContextMeta` class and they've obviously had to do a lot of work to make it all work.

Comment: @joanis thanks for your swift reply. I also really like the API and hoped it was something I could implement for my own use cases. I will dig into the code and try to understand how they accomplish this. I was hoping for a simple example how they do this in general. But do understand now that it is more advanced concept overall. Thanks!